# Getting user input within tqdm loops

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I'm writing a script where a user has to provide input for each element of a large list. I'm trying to use `tqdm` to provide a progress bar for the user, but I can't find a good way to get input within the `tqdm` loop without breaking the output.

I'm aware of `tqdm.write()` for writing to the terminal during a `tqdm` loop, but is there a way of getting input?

For an example of what I'm trying to do, consider the code below:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys
from time import sleep

def do_stuff(x): sleep(0.5)

stuff_list = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega']

for thing in tqdm(stuff_list):
    input_string = input(thing + ": ")
    do_stuff(input_string)
```

If I run this code, I get the following output:

```
0%|                                                                                            | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Alpha: A
 25%|█████████████████████                                                               | 1/4 [00:02<00:07,  2.54s/it]Beta: B
 50%|██████████████████████████████████████████                                          | 2/4 [00:03<00:04,  2.09s/it]Gamma: C
 75%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████                     | 3/4 [00:04<00:01,  1.72s/it]Omega: D
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4/4 [00:05<00:00,  1.56s/it]
```

I've tried using `tqdm.external_write_mode`, but this simply didn't display the progress bar whenever an input was waiting, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for.

Is there an easy way of doing this, or am I going to have to swap libraries?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, the code you provided works for me. In case the automatic line break doesn't work, what if you change your input to `input_string = input("\n" + thing + ": ")`?

Comment: That will work for getting each prompt on a new line (which I should've probably done for this example). However, my goal is for there to be only one progress bar which gets updated - similar to the behaviour when using `tqdm.write()`.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? I have a solution that is quite close to what you need, if you are on linux. I don't think that a solution for windows exists.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to display the progress bar while inside the input() function, because once a line is finished, it cannot be removed any more. It's a technical limitation of how command lines work. You can only remove the current line until you wrote a newline.

Therefore, I think the only solution is to remove the status bar, let the user input happen and then display it again.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys
from time import sleep

def do_stuff(x): sleep(0.5)

stuff_list = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega']

# To have more fine-control, you need to create a tqdm object
progress_iterator = tqdm(stuff_list)

for thing in progress_iterator:
    # Remove progress bar
    progress_iterator.clear()

    # User input
    input_string = input(thing + ": ")

    # Write the progress bar again
    progress_iterator.refresh()

    # Do stuff
    do_stuff(input_string)
```

If you don't like the fact that the progress_iterator object exists after the loop, use the `with` syntax:

```
with tqdm(stuff_list) as progress_iterator:
    for thing in progress_iterator:
        ...
```

**EDIT:**
If you are willed to sacrifice platform independence, you can freely move the cursor and delete lines with [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-the-last-printed-line-in-Python-language):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys
from time import sleep

def do_stuff(x): sleep(0.5)

stuff_list = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega']

# Special console commands
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'

# To have more fine-control, you need to create a tqdm object
progress_iterator = tqdm(stuff_list)

for thing in progress_iterator:

    # Move the status bar one down
    progress_iterator.clear()
    print(file=sys.stderr)
    progress_iterator.refresh()

    # Move the cursor back up
    sys.stderr.write('\r')
    sys.stderr.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)

    # User input
    input_string = input(thing + ": ")

    # Refresh the progress bar, to move the cursor back to where it should be.
    # This step can be omitted.
    progress_iterator.refresh()

    # Do stuff
    do_stuff(input_string)
```

I think this is the closest you will get to `tqdm.write()`. Note that the behaviour of `input()` can never be identical to `tqdm.write()`, because `tqdm.write()` first deletes the bar, then writes the message, and then writes the bar again. If you want to display the bar while being in `input()`, you *have* to do some platform-dependent stuff like this.