# tqdm progress bar with requested input of first iteration

Tags: python, tqdm

My code iterates over files in the current folder, and requests user input on the first iteration. I want to show a `tqdm` progress bar, but that doesn't look good as the bar is "broken" after the user input:

```py
In [1]: import os
   ...: import tqdm
   ...: from time import sleep

In [2]: with tqdm.tqdm(total=5000) as progress:
   ...:     for f in range(4):
   ...:         if f == 0:
   ...:             my_input = input('type something: ')
   ...:         sleep(1)
   ...:         progress.update(1000)
   ...:
  0%|                                                                                         | 0/5000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]type something: a
 80%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▌               | 4000/5000 [00:05<00:01, 712.32it/s]
```

I guess I would need to create the `progress` object during the first iteration of the loop after the input using an internal loop counter? Or is there a better way?

Comment: there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794701/7540911)  it comes down to putting a `progress.clear()` before your `input` and then putting a `progress.refresh()` after

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks!